# Regex extraction in R

Tags: regex, r, stringr

I'm working on a project which uses Multidimensional Scaling to try and group politicians together based on voting records. My goodness of fit is high; however, I want to plot the MDS coordinates with the names of the politicians so I can draw conclusions from the computation. I am using the wordcloud library for this.

I am attempting to use regex in R using the stringr package to extract the names of the politicians from my "names" vector, the names vector contains some non-standard characters. My goal is to extract the last name and the characters in the square brackets. There are 3 different ways the names look and they are below:

- Sen. Mike Lee [R]
- Sen. Chris Coons [D, 2010-2020]
- Sen. Charles â€œChuckâ€ Grassley [R]

From the stringr package I am running this code:

```
str_extract("\\w+\\s\\[.+\\]$", names)  # names is the vector of names
```

I get this error:

```
Error in UseMethod("type") : 
  no applicable method for 'type' applied to an object of class "NULL"
```

I'm trying to diagnose this error yet can't seem to find anything online to help.

Comment: firstly convert your names to character by `df$colname<-as.character(df$colname)`

Comment: First, you confused the args order in `str_replace`: it must be `str_extract(names, "\\w+\\s\\[.+\\]$")`.Second, you will get `[1] "Lee [R]"              "Coons [D, 2010-2020]" "Grassley [R]"`. Third, what result do you expect?

Comment: The result you posted is what I expect, with those elements for each element of my vector.

Comment: Thank you, I feel dumb now since I was mixing up the stringr documentation and other documentation about r regex functions. This solved my problem. Thank you.

Comment: I posted my comment with more details as an answer. Please use `@` + username when writing back a comment, or the user won't get notified.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You confused the argument order in `str_replace`: it must be `str_extract(names, "\\w+\\s\\[.+\\]$")` (that is, `names` should be the first argument, and the regex must be the second argument. You will get

```
> str_extract(names, "\\w+\\s\\[.+\\]$")
[1] "Lee [R]"              "Coons [D, 2010-2020]" "Grassley [R]"
```

Note that you can remove the escaping symbol from `]` since it is not a special regex metacharacter and you can replace `.+` with a negated character class `[^][]+` to match any one or more characters other than `]` and `[`:

```
> str_extract(names, "\\w+\\s\\[[^\\]\\[]+]$")
[1] "Lee [R]"              "Coons [D, 2010-2020]" "Grassley [R]"
```

Answer (score 0):

Given

```
names <- c("Sen. Mike Lee [R]", "Sen. Chris Coons [D, 2010-2020]", "Sen. Charles â€œChuckâ€ Grassley [R]")
stringr::str_extract("\\w+\\s\\[.+\\]$", names)  # names is the vector of names
# [1] NA NA NA
```

and

```
t(sapply(regmatches(names, regexec(".*\\s(\\w+)\\s\\[(.+)\\]", names)), "[", -1))
#      [,1]       [,2]          
# [1,] "Lee"      "R"           
# [2,] "Coons"    "D, 2010-2020"
# [3,] "Grassley" "R"
```

I cannot reproduce your error.

Comment: Thank you, it works in the RStudio console, but I still can't get it to work in my script for some reason.

Comment: Encoding issues? You should always provide a reproducible example for copy-paste-run.

Comment: I'll do that in the future, my error came from mixing up the argument order in str_extract as pointed out in the comments above. Thank you